# How to enable Alert manager pick alert manager configs from a new kubernetes namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

Alertmanager(`kind: Alertmanager`) is running in `prometh` namespace.

We have access to push alert rule definitions(`kind: PrometheusRule`) to `prometh` namespace, with additional labels in alert payload(`sourceNamespace` & `destinationNamespace`), as shown below:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: service-prometheus
    role: alert-rules
    app: kube-prometheus-stack
    release: monitoring-prom
  name: rule_a
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  groups:
    - name: rule_a_alert
      rules:
        - alert: usage_exceed
          expr: salesforce_api_usage > 100000
          labels:
            severity: urgent
            sourceNamespace: app-dev
            destinationNamespace: prometh
```

---

Value of `sourceNamespace` indicate the namespace where application pods are running.

We have alert manager config(`kind: AlertmanagerConfig`) that match with rule definition(above) using below syntax:

```
route:
  routes:
  - match:
      severity: urgent
```

but we do not have access to push alert manager config into `prometh` namespace. we have access to push alert manager config only into `app-dev`

---

Is it possible to start alert manager, by enabling it to register new alertmanager configs from a new `sourceNamespace` in runtime? with `alertmanager.alertmanagerSpec.alertmanagerConfigNamespaceSelector` field

Related discussion: https://issueexplorer.com/issue/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/4263